# Delete parts of a string using batch

Tags: batch-file

Hello I'm working on this file and I can't seem to get around this problem 
Now this works great if I make many scripts for all my strings. 
But would really like help with making one scripts

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set input=asset_database_Release.txt
set output=asset_database_Release_ready.txt
set "substr={"code":"*_icon","type":"?","version":"??"},"

(
    FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%G IN ("%input%") DO (
        set line=%%G
        echo. !line:%substr%=!
    )
) > "%output%"

EndLocal
exit /b 0
```

In my text file I have 1000 strings that look like this

```
{"code":"The_Great_Place_icon","type":"8","version":"80"},"
{"code":"The_Great_Area_icon","type":"10","version":"60"},"
{"code":"The_Great_Earth_icon","type":"23","version":"75"},"
```

If I set the script like this, it works and only removes that section

```
set "substr={"code":""
```

If I make a second script and set then script like this, it works and only removes that section

```
set "substr=_icon","type":"8","version":"80"},"
```

But I would have to make over 1000 scripts to clean out the extra not needed 
the results should be like this

```
The_Great_Place
The_Great_Area
The_Great_Earth
```

Comment: All of Mofi's comments are good advice. Another option (assuming your files are consistently structured as you listed) is to use [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) - `jrepl "^.*?:\q(.*?)_icon\q" "$txt=$1" /xseq /jmatchq /f "asset_database_Release.txt" /o "asset_database_Release_ready.txt"`

Comment: @dbenham - I see what this is jrepl is the action, this : is located before "The, and _icon so this is designed to remove everything before and after The_Great_Place, but nothing happen, didn't run

Comment: @JavierRivas - I just put your example lines in a text file and tested the JREPL code I gave you, and it gave your expected output.

Comment: @JavierRivas - JREPL is not a standard command. If you want it then you need to get a free copy at the link I provided. It is a hybrid JScript/batch utility script file that runs on any Windows machine from XP onward - no 3rd party exe or dll required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data extraction task can be done for the JSON data in the file with following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
(for /F "usebackq tokens=2 delims=:," %%I in ("asset_database_Release.txt") do (
    set "Value=%%~I"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo !Value:_icon=!
    endlocal
))>"asset_database_Release_ready.txt"
endlocal
```

It would be also possible to code that all in a single command line working with defaults for command extensions (enabled) and delayed environment variable expansion (disabled):

```
@(for /F "usebackq tokens=2 delims=:," %%I in ("asset_database_Release.txt") do @set "Value=%%~I" & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & echo !Value:_icon=!&endlocal)>"asset_database_Release_ready.txt"
```

The command **FOR** with option `/F` processes the lines in file `asset_database_Release.txt` in current directory one line after the other whereby empty lines are ignored by **FOR**.

A line read from the file is by default split up into substrings (tokens) using normal space and horizontal tab as string delimiters. The list of delimiters is modified with `delims=:,` to colon and comma which means a line like

```
{"code":"The_Great_Place_icon","type":"8","version":"80"},"
```

is split up to

1. `{"code"`
2. `"The_Great_Place_icon"`
3. `"type"`
4. `"8"`
5. `"version"`
6. `"80"}`
7. `"`

There is next evaluated by **FOR** if the first substring starts with a semicolon because of `;` is the default end of line character. The line is ignored if that is the case. The JSON formatted data lines in the file do not start with a semicolon and so the implicit default `eol=;` can be kept for this task.

There would be assigned next by default just the first substring to the specified loop variable `I`. This behavior is not wanted here. The second substring is of interest which is the reason for using the option `tokens=2`.

The option `usebackq` is used to get the file name enclosed in double quotes interpreted not as string to split up into substrings, but as name of the file of which lines should be processed by **FOR**.

The second substring is assigned next to the environment variable `Value` with removing the surrounding double quotes.

Then [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is enabled with the command `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` which does following in the background:

1. Push current directory path on stack.
2. Push current status of command extensions on stack.
3. Push current status of delayed expansion on stack.
4. Push a pointer to the current list of environment variables on stack.
5. Make a copy of current list of environment variables for usage in new local environment.
6. Enable delayed expansion according to the used option.

Delayed environment variable expansion is required for the next command to replace case-insensitive all occurrences of `_icon` by an empty string which means removing all `_icon` occurrences from the string assigned to environment variable `Value` and to output the remaining string which is hopefully not an empty string as that would result in output of current status of command echo mode.

The command `endlocal` is executed next to avoid a stack overflow. It does following in the background:

1. Discard the current list of environment variables.
2. Pop pointer to previous list of environment variables from stack and use it to reactivate this list.
3. Pop previous status of delayed expansion from stack and set delayed expansion status accordingly.
4. Pop previous status of command extensions from stack and set command extensions status accordingly.
5. Pop previous current directory path from stack and set this directory again as current directory if the directory still exists.

Everything output by the command **ECHO** inside the **FOR** loop to handle **STDOUT** is redirected by the Windows command processor `cmd.exe` into the file `asset_database_Release_ready.txt` in current directory with overwriting a perhaps already existing file with that file name.

It would be possible to enable delayed expansion already above the **FOR** loop with using:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
(for /F "usebackq tokens=2 delims=:," %%I in ("asset_database_Release.txt") do (
    set "Value=%%~I"
    echo !Value:_icon=!
))>"asset_database_Release_ready.txt"
endlocal
```

That would make the processing of the lines in JSON file faster. But the disadvantages are that the two file names without or with path must not contain one or more exclamation marks and the second substring of each non-empty line in file must be also always without an exclamation mark because of the exclamation marks would be interpreted in this case as beginning/end of a delayed expanded environment variable reference.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of the redirection operator `>`.

---

There are available **by default** since Windows Vista three script interpreters:

1. The **Windows command processor** `cmd.exe` is interpreting `.bat` and `.cmd` batch files. It is designed for executing commands and executables. It has no function to search and replace something in a file nor is there any [Windows Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) which supports that.
2. The **Windows Script Host** `cscript.exe` (Windows console version) or `wscript.exe` (Windows GUI version) is interpreting by default `.vbs` and `.vbe` **VBScript** files and `.js` and `.jse` **JScript** files. But it can be used for even more scripting languages on having other script interpreters installed and configured for being used by Windows Script Host.
3. **PowerShell** is interpreting `.ps1` PowerShell script files. **PowerShell** is the official successor of the Windows command processor and is much more powerful than **CMD**. It has, depending on the PowerShell version, built-in support for regular expression search and replace in files as well as real support for JSON data parsing.

**PowerShell** would be much better for this JSON data extraction task than the batch files posted above working only for the text files with contents as posted in the question. The batch file would not work if the JSON data are on a single line in the file or there is a comma or colon inside `code` value.

The website [ss64.com](https://ss64.com/) offers comprehensive information for all three script interpreters, their syntax and their functions and commands.

PowerShell 2.0 is also available as free optional Windows component for Windows XP SP3.

Comment: all perfect all great

Answer (score 1):

Another approach (given limited amount of test data)

```batch-file
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
rem The following settings for the source directory, destination directory, target directory,
rem batch directory, filenames, output filename and temporary filename [if shown] are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q66497185.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"

(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%b IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 rem line in %%b
 FOR /F "tokens=2delims=:," %%e IN ("%%b") DO (
  SET "icon=%%~e"
  ECHO !icon:~0,-5!
 )
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

The setup section is a template I use often. Adjust to suit yourself.

Read the file lines to `%%b`. and extract the quoted name by selecting the part between the first `:` and the succeeding `,` to `%%e`.

Set a standard variable to the value of `%%e`, removing quotes with the `~` modifier.

Then output the required name by `echo`ing all but the last 5 characters of the variable.

Comment: Very Nice Thank you this also works, and this will work for me on other task, How can I check 2 answers, or only votes

Comment: "How can I check 2 answers," Not possible.

Comment: OK Thank you very much, I have voted on both

Answer (score 0):

you can go into the edit menu and press on the find option, then type in the text of the 1000 lines you need to delete since they all start with the same input, then press find, and you can find them yourself to fix it, also you could use the replace feature too.

Comment: yes that is true, but the problem is that all 1000 lines have the same start input, the name and version are different, what I used to do was find and replace, find {"code":" and replace with nothing, but the problem with that are the version numbers, not  all have the same numbers, so I would have to do find and replace 1000 times, trust me that gets tiring fast